# Is it possible to add custom parameters to @SQLDelete override in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Is it possible to add custom parameters to @SQLDelete override in Hibernate?  I don't want to have to edit Hibernate source code.  In the example below I am trying to include a lastUpdatedBy column in the delete query.

Thanks for any help.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE user SET deleted='Y', version=version+1 WHERE id=? AND version=? AND lastUpdatedBy = ?")
public class User  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "deleted")
    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    protected boolean deleted;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version", nullable = false)
    protected Integer version;

    @Column(name = "last_updated_by")
    protected Long lastUpdatedBy;

    ...

}
```

Comment: Hi, i want to know the solution too, do you get it?

Comment: hi Thomas, I got one solution, if you need, I will share with you

Comment: Yeah post it and I'll give you credit!

Comment: please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Below is example code, you can follow such code that override the delete event manually:

```
public class CustomDeleteEventListener extends DefaultDeleteEventListener implements DeleteEventListener {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CustomDeleteEventListener.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    /**
     * Override the default delete logic here, handle the given delete event.
     *
     * @param event DeleteEvent object which can get hibernate session or entity
     * @param transientEntities The cache of entities already deleted
     * @throws HibernateException
     */
    @Override
    public void onDelete(DeleteEvent event, Set transientEntities) throws HibernateException {
        // get current deleting entity from event
        Object entity = event.getObject();
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("entity class type is " + entity.getClass());
        }
        if (entity instanceof User) {
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug("Detect delete User event, delegate to user service to do soft deletion. entity type: " + entity.getClass());
            }
            userService.removeUser((User) entity);
        } else {
            // other entities still follow their default logic
            super.onDelete(event, transientEntities);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't quite answer the question, but it's one approach